# Javascript Regex: How to avoid catastrophic backtracking in this case

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match string like `[[[[145.139038,-37.933533],[145.084]]]]`.

So I have following regex: `^\[{2,}(\d|-|.|\[|\]|)+\]{2,}$`, which works fine. But the problem arises when I have an extra character at the end of the string.

For example `[[[[145.139038,-37.933533],[145.084]]]]}` in this case. Then it explodes.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It didn't match for larger string. Here is an example:
https://regex101.com/r/5QOihq/3

Comment: What is `…` character in your input?

Comment: Opss my bad added there by mistake. Thank you it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't seem right as you have an empty alternation. Many single character alternations can be expressed in a character class `[...]`.

This regex should work for your input data:

```
/^\[{2,}([-\d.\[\],\s]+)\]{2,}$/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5QOihq/4)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want.

Easiest, is to remove the `$` at the very end, as it as matching the end of the string. Regex would be: `^\[{2,}(\d|-|.|\[|\]|)+\]{2,}`
See: https://regex101.com/r/5QOihq/1

If you want to match for exactly your string, and allow as many other characters after that until the end of the string, you could go for: `^(\[{2,}(\d|-|.|\[|\]|)+\]{2,}).*$`
https://regex101.com/r/5QOihq/2

---

Updated after comment with more examples: `\[((?:[+-]?)\d+\.[\d…]+,\s(?:[+-]?)\d+\.[\d…]+(?:,\s\d+\.[\d…]+)?)\]`
https://regex101.com/r/5QOihq/6

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so quickly. But it didn't work for larger strings :(
https://regex101.com/r/5QOihq/5

Comment: Updated your example: https://regex101.com/r/5QOihq/6

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know why the regex engine see's this as too
complex, it is because the dot `.` matches all the other alternation
characters. So when the engine backtracks it has to find all the combinations
over and over again.

```
 ^ 
 \[{2,} 
 (                  # (1 start)
    \d 
  | -
  | .                  # <- dot matches \d,-,[,]
  | \[ 
  | \] 
    # | <- do not allow nothing really
 )+                 # (1 end)
 \]{2,} 
 $
```